# Why I can't CALL "IF" and "FOR" neither in batch nor in the cmd?

Tags: batch-file

To be honest I don't expect a satisfying answer here.These command cannot be called and that's it (as far as I know the only commands that cannot be used with call).
Here are few examples with their output:

```
C:\Windows\system32>call @if a==a echo called 
',' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Windows\system32>call (@if a==a echo called)
';' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Windows\system32>call if a==a echo called
'if' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Windows\system32>call for  %a in (1) do @echo called
'for' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Windows\system32>call @for  %a in (1) do @echo called
'+' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Windows\system32>call (@for  %a in (1) do @echo called)
';' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I have some suspicious , that IF and FOR are not in fact 'real' commands - they just decide to pass the command prompt  control to the line (or brackets block) behind them or not , which confuses the call.
Anyway even that , when there are syntax errors in called FOR or IF  they are detected:

```
C:\Windows\system32>call (@if a= echo called)
= was unexpected at this time.

C:\Windows\system32>call (for %a (1) do echo called)
(1 was unexpected at this time.
```

So at least the parsing is done.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are quite right.

`FOR`, `IF` and `REM` aren't *normal* internal commands (but for REM exists also a normal internal version).
They use an own special parser (each a different one).

It seems that these commands are translated to a sort of token.
Therefor you got such unexpected error messages (there are much more possible characters), the error/token character depends also of the Windows version (if I remember correct here).
Probably the `CALL` command sees only the tokenized data from the original command.

Command blocks don't work at all with the call command, also `&|<>` don't work as expected.

```
call (a^|a)
```

Searches for a command/token `2`, so if you create a batch file named `2.bat` you can start it with `call (a^|a)`.

For further information about `CALL`
[Dostips:CALL me, or better avoid call](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=1947)
[Dostips:Limit CMD processing to internal commands, safer and faster?](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=2521)

Answer (score 4):

After all it is possible to call IF and FOR ..or almost;

```
    @echo off

rem :: this will produce an error
rem if a equ a

rem :: And this too
rem call if a equ a rem

rem :: But this will not!!!
call if a equ a

rem :: This will not too ((\but in command prompt single % is enough)
call for %%%%a in (.) do

rem :: And this
call if a equ a for %%%%a in (.) do if 1 equ 1  for %%%%a in (.) do if c==c

rem :: And this
call if a equ a for %%%%a in (.) do if 1 equ 1 for %%%%a in (.) do if c==c ( rem rem rem echo something
```

Despite I see no usage of this.

Comment: +1 It's impressive how much things you've tested (not only these ones). And thereby you found many interessting things

Answer (score 1):

this way works :
call cmd.exe /c if a==a echo called.