# Batch-Script - Iterate through arguments

Tags: loops, batch-file, arguments, command-line-arguments

I have a batch-script with multiple arguments. I am reading the total count of them and then run a for loop like this:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set argCount=0
for %%x in (%*) do set /A argCount+=1
echo Number of processed arguments: %argCount%

set /a counter=0
for /l %%x in (1, 1, %argCount%) do (
set /a counter=!counter!+1 )
```

What I want to do now, is to use my running variable (`x` or `counter`) to access the input arguments. I am thinking aobut something like this:

```
REM Access to %1 
echo %(!counter!)
```

In an ideal world this line should print out my first command line argument but obviously it doesn't. I know I am doing something wrong with the `%` operator, but is there anyway I could access my arguments like this?

//edit: Just to make things clear - the problem is that `%(!counter!)` provides me with the value of the variable `counter`. Meaning for `counter=2` it gives me `2` and not the content of `%2`.

Comment: if the arguments are more than 9 you can't access all of them without `shift`

Comment: This is another issue I might encounter, but let's just assume that I will have less than 10 arguments

Comment: Also, `for %%x in (%*) do ...` will not give the desired result if any parameter contains `*` or `?` character. I always use a GOTO loop with SHIFT if I want to load the parameters into an array of variables.

Comment: If one of the arguments contains a wildcard character, e.g. "file*.txt" then it is not processed. Any idea how to fix?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

here's one way to access the second (e.g.) argument (this can be put in a `for /l` loop, see below.):

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set /a counter=2
call echo %%!counter!
endlocal
```

so:

```
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set /a counter=0
for /l %%x in (1, 1, %argCount%) do (
 set /a counter=!counter!+1
 call echo %%!counter! 
)
endlocal
```

Comment: Ok I need to ask, even if it may obvious and I am just having a blackout: Is there any way how I can get that value into a variable now? Now that I have read the Input paramaeters I want to compare them with some strings. And I am not quite sure how I can access that string now...?

Comment: with call `set "_var=%%!counter!"`.you need a temp variable because  [if cannot be called](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19445153/why-i-cant-call-if-and-for-neither-in-batch-nor-in-the-cmd)

Comment: and then you can compare with if -> `if "!_var!" equ "something" echo this is something`

Comment: Are you sure that I have to put the `"` around the whole `set` call?

Comment: it is `a safe` strategy. this allows you to include special characters in the value like `|&><....` and will ensure you that there is no extra space at the end (which in some cases could break your logic)

Comment: The problem is, when I assign it to `_var` , `_var` also just contains `%1` etc (using `echo !_var!`) - When I use `call echo !_var!` I get the contents again - the problem is when I use `_var` in my `if` call (liek you suggest) it unfortunately doesn't work

Comment: `call set` ...the call accidentally was left outside the grey bckg.

Comment: `call set "_var=%%!counter!"`

Comment: Be aware that this needs the delayed expansion (`setlocal enableDelayedExpansion`), which my [preferred answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39776524/4575793) doesn't. You could also add an `@echo off` in front.

Comment: @Cadoiz - mind that using labels and GOTO for loops can be low performing approach.

Answer (score 76):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set argCount=0
for %%x in (%*) do (
   set /A argCount+=1
   set "argVec[!argCount!]=%%~x"
)

echo Number of processed arguments: %argCount%

for /L %%i in (1,1,%argCount%) do echo %%i- "!argVec[%%i]!"
```

For example:

```
C:> test One "This is | the & second one" Third
Number of processed arguments: 3
1- "One"
2- "This is | the & second one"
3- "Third"
```

Another one:

```
C:> test One Two Three Four Five Six Seven Eight Nine Ten Eleven Twelve etc...
Number of processed arguments: 13
1- "One"
2- "Two"
3- "Three"
4- "Four"
5- "Five"
6- "Six"
7- "Seven"
8- "Eight"
9- "Nine"
10- "Ten"
11- "Eleven"
12- "Twelve"
13- "etc..."
```

Comment: Tthis one is working as is, for me, unlike current solution from @npocmaka (windows 10 familly)

Comment: A little more context on how the whole thing works would be nice, but the solutions does what it says on the thin, I give you that. :-)

Comment: This has trouble when the argument has some format, e.g. this link: `https://www.tagesschau.de/investigativ/ndr-wdr/spaeh-software-pegasus-projekt-101.html`. I can't name the exact problem, but it doesn't even count this argument. It probably also has problems if one of the argument contains `*`.

Comment: Be aware that this needs the delayed expansion (`setlocal enableDelayedExpansion`), which my [preferred answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39776524/4575793) doesn't.

Comment: This answer splits on semicolons. Calling with "One;Two" will output two lines "One" and "Two".

Comment: @Hypershadsy: Not true. If you call it with `"One;Two"` (enclosed in quotes) it output just one line. If you don't enclose parameters in quotes, then the usual Batch rules apply: parameters are split at semicolon, comma or equal-sign (besides spaces). For example: `test One;Two,Three=Four`

Answer (score 38):

```
:loop
@echo %1
shift
if not "%~1"=="" goto loop
```

Comment: Where are the better answers?  I like this one because it is super succinct, minimal, and straightforward.

Comment: What I think @jeb is trying to say is that you should provide an explanation for your answer. I think it's great, but with details on what each command does, and maybe a usage example, you'll get more upvotes :)

Comment: This answer works when the arguments contain special characters like `*` but iterates one time too many when there are no arguments.

Comment: Very helpful information @Arnaud, thank you for explaining the issue and shedding light on this!

Comment: that's my choice, for sure!

Comment: Found this to be by far the most reliable solution. It also handles `parameter_iteration_3.bat https://www.tagesschau.de/investigativ/ndr-wdr/spaeh-software-pegasus-smartphone-101.html?utm_source=pocket-newtab-global-de-DE ** * te*st` as the only solution and also correctly deals with `""`

Comment: This breaks when an empty argument `""` is in the mix, skipping anything after. Also, I can't get this version to preserve equals signs :(

Answer (score 11):

If to keep the code short rather than wise, then

```
for %%x in (%*) do (
   echo Hey %%~x 
)
```

Comment: Is this approach unwise?  And if so, why?

Comment: @isapir This approach will fail if one of the argument contains `*` as I just learned the hard way.

Comment: this one is more understandable than @JayTaylor's answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/39776524/209942

Answer (score 2):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET nparms=0
FOR /l %%i IN (1,1,20) DO (
 SET myparm=%%i
 CALL :setparm %*
 IF DEFINED myparm SET nparms=%%i&CALL ECHO Parameter %%i=%%myparm%%
)
ECHO there were %nparms% parameters in %*
GOTO :EOF

:setparm
IF %myparm%==1 SET myparm=%1&GOTO :EOF
shift&SET /a myparm -=1&GOTO setparm
GOTO :eof
```

This should show how to extract random parameters by position.

Comment: Are you counting the number of command-line arguments?

Comment: @johnywhy No, that was done in the original post. This demonstration is of how to access any arbitrary parameter by position since for instance %13 to get the 13th parameter will actually tag "3" onto the end of the first parameter (%1) as only a single digit is allowed in this position. The demo shows the first 20 parameters as set by the `for/l` loop. The number in `nparms` is actually the last-detected parameter number that was defined. Change the loop to `for %%i in (6,3,25,11,9) do` and it will report the last parameter number defined of the set `(6,3,25,11,9)` as `nparms`

Answer (score 2):

For simple iteration can't we just check for additional arguments with "shift /1" at the end of the code and loop back? This will handle more than 10 arguments, upper limit not tested.

```
:loop

:: Your code using %1
echo %1

:: Check for further batch arguments.     
shift /1
IF [%1]==[] (
goto end
) ELSE (
goto loop
)

:end
pause
```