# Why can I not get a substring of a delayed expansion variable in an if statement?

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, cmd, delayedvariableexpansion

Why does string-manipulation work inline in an if statement without using delayed expansion variables - but fails otherwise. For example:

```
set test=testString
if %test:~0,4%==test echo Success
```

This works correctly; returning `Success`. However if I do the following:

```
setLocal enableDelayedExpansion
set test=testString
if !test:~0,4!==test echo Success
```

I receive the error - `4!==test was unexpected at this time.`

Obviously you can get around this by doing something like `set comp=!test:~0,4!` then just using the `!comp!` variable in the if statement.

Comment: `if "!test:~0,4!" equ "test" echo Success` - works this way , but of course this not an answer...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

npocmaka correctly diagnosed the problem that the IF command gets its own special parsing phase, and token delimiters within the variable expansion are causing problems.

Substitution also causes a problem:

```
:: This fails
if !test:String=!==test echo Success
```

The reason why normal expansion works is because that occurs before the IF parsing, but delayed expansion occurs *after* IF parsing.

An alternative to using quotes is to escape the problem characters.

```
:: Both of these work
if !test:~0^,4!==test echo Success
if !test:String^=!==test echo Success
```

Answer (score 10):

`,;=<tab>` and `<space>` are delimiters for cmd.exe and in many cases are ignored if they are not in quotes and act  like empty space.Probably in this case `,` is taken as the end of the first operand and `IF` is surprised that there is not valid comparison operator e.g. this will print `yep` :

```
if a   ;==;,,=a echo yep
```

(but will not work if there's a equal sign in the first part of the operands)

But this will not:

`if "a   ;" == ";,,=a" echo yep`

so to make a valid `IF` expression when you use comma you need quotes.And this will work

```
setLocal enableDelayedExpansion
set test=testString
if "!test:~0,4!" == "test" echo Success
```

Without delayed expansion substitution is made immediately and this will work without quotes:

```
set test=testString
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
if %test:~0,4% == test echo Succes
endlocal
```

[For the same reason this will be taken as a wrong syntax expression](http://ss64.org/viewtopic.php?id=1709) (see jeb's comment):

```
set "test="
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
if %test% == test echo Succes
endlocal
```

May be is not the complete answer , but should be close.As both `echo !test:~0,4!` and `echo %test:~0,4%` will work without quotes stays the question why exactly `IF` fails - [may because `IF` command uses its own parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19445153/why-i-cant-call-if-and-for-neither-in-batch-nor-in-the-cmd)

As a conclusion - it's always good to use quotes when you compare strings with `IF` :

1. with delayed expansion commas and semicolons will cause troubles.
2. without delayed expansion undefined variables will cause troubles.

Comment: Why does it not do the same for `%test:~0,4%`?

Comment: Good answer - I think you're closing point was correct. Though, as you say, it doesn't completely answer the question. I'll mark this answer as correct in a while - if I don't get a more concise answer. Thank you very much.

Comment: The key is that delayedexpansion is precisely that - delayed until execution time. At PARSE time, %var...% is resolved and substituted, but !var...! is not - it will be substituted at RUN time and is interpreted as a simple string. The parser thus sees *string*[separator]*string*==*string* but is expecting *string*[operator]*string*. The second string that the parser sees doesn't match its list of valid operators, so the parser calls the command invalid.