# Searching substring in the string - unexpected at this time

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to determine if option is define statement/option for the VC compiler (/DSOME_OPTION=1 e.g.). Here is the part of options handling loop, which return error "Unexpected at this time: =option.". I've used search substring solution from [StackOverflow: Batch file: Find if substring is in string (not in a file)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7005951/batch-file-find-if-substring-is-in-string-not-in-a-file)

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
:loop
if not "%~1"=="" (
    rem all defines
    set "option=%~1"
    if x%option:/D=%==x%option% (
        set DEFINE_STR=%DEFINE_STR% %~1
        echo "DEFINE_STR=%DEFINE_STR%"
        pause
    )
    shift
    goto :loop
)
```

Comment: the first equal sign...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
@echo off

setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "DEFINE_STR="
:loop
if not "%~1"=="" (
    rem all defines
    set "option=%~1"
    if "!option:/D=!" == "!option!" (
        set "DEFINE_STR=!DEFINE_STR! %~1"
        echo "DEFINE_STR=!DEFINE_STR!"
        pause
    )
    shift
    goto :loop
)
endlocal
```

In this question you can find more info -> [Why can I not get a substring of a delayed expansion variable in an if statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20339341/why-can-i-not-get-a-substring-of-a-delayed-expansion-variable-in-an-if-statement)

Comment: do you have a brackets in `%1` ?

Comment: @AntonKochkov you also need delayed expansion because you are changing a variable in a brackets...Check my update