# How to use delayedexpansion to handle value in batch script

Tags: batch-file, cmd, special-characters, delayedvariableexpansion

I am facing issue with reading contents of CSV files in batch script. I have a series of files say `My_A_File.csv, My_B_File.csv ... My_Z_File.csv`. The issue I was facing is reading special characters in them. Hence, wanted to read the values with delayedexpansion turned off.

When I read the values in the block with disabledelayedexpansion, they are empty! How can I handle this?

**Script:**

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /L %%g in (65,1,90) do (
    cmd /c exit /b %%g
    set codeval=!=ExitCodeAscii!
    set fileToReadFrom=My_!codeval!_File.csv

    if exist My_!codeval!_File.csv (
        echo Outer-!fileToReadFrom!
        echo Outer-!codeval!
        setlocal disabledelayedexpansion
        echo Inner-%fileToReadFrom%
        echo Inner-%codeval%
        endlocal
    )
)
```

**Output:**

```
Outer-My_A_File.csv
Outer-A
Inner-
Inner-
```

Comment: In the line `set codeval=!=ExitCodeAscii!`, there is a second `=` which I guess is not intended to be there; am I right?

Comment: @aschipfl this is a [special variable](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-variables.html) that contains the exit code as ascii character

Comment: Wow, very interesting, @npocmaka, I was not aware of that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This how the delayed expansion is supposed to work.However you can access the variables with `CALL` but this will the performance (mind that you cant [CALL FOR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19445153/why-i-cant-call-if-and-for-neither-in-batch-nor-in-the-cmd) ):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /L %%g in (65,1,90) do (
    cmd /c exit /b %%g
    set codeval=!=ExitCodeAscii!
    set fileToReadFrom=My_!codeval!_File.csv

    if exist My_!codeval!_File.csv (
        echo Outer-!fileToReadFrom!
        echo Outer-!codeval!
        setlocal disabledelayedexpansion
          call echo Inner-%%fileToReadFrom%%
          call echo Inner-%%codeval%%
        endlocal
    )
)
```

or you can use pipes.Which also will hit the performance (now you can use 
`break|for "usebackq" %%a in ("Inner-%%fileToReadFrom%%") do @echo %%~a`):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /L %%g in (65,1,90) do (
    cmd /c exit /b %%g
    set codeval=!=ExitCodeAscii!
    set fileToReadFrom=My_!codeval!_File.csv

    if exist My_!codeval!_File.csv (
        echo Outer-!fileToReadFrom!
        echo Outer-!codeval!
        setlocal disabledelayedexpansion
           break|echo Inner-%%fileToReadFrom%%
           break|echo Inner-%%codeval%%
        endlocal
    )
)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a subroutine to process code with delayed expansion disabled as follows:

```
@echo off
rem skip subroutine code
goto :toMain

:toProcessDDE
  rem subroutine to process delayed expansion disabled
  setlocal disabledelayedexpansion
  echo Inner-%fileToReadFrom%
  echo Inner-%codeval%
  endlocal
exit /B

:toMain
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /L %%g in (65,1,90) do (
    cmd /c exit /b %%g
    set codeval=!=ExitCodeAscii!
    set fileToReadFrom=My_!codeval!_File.csv

    if exist My_!codeval!_File.csv (
        echo Outer-!fileToReadFrom!
        echo Outer-!codeval!
        call :toProcessDDE
    )
)
```

Read

- [CALL: Call one batch program from another, or call a subroutine](http://ss64.com/nt/call.html) and
- [EXIT: … quit the current subroutine …](http://ss64.com/nt/exit.html)