# Why does this command crash cmd?

Tags: cmd

I came across a mind-blowing [weird script](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/tree/master/discovers_and_bugs/bugs) that **crashes the console**:

```
set "h=/?" & call [if | for | rem] %%h%%
```

- `IF`, `FOR` and `REM` [aren't normal internal commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19445153/why-i-cant-call-if-and-for-neither-in-batch-nor-in-the-cmd).
  They use an own special parser, which possibly caused some interception errors so it crashed.

**@jeb** pointed out `CALL`  [doesn't execute the following special characters](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=1947), but instead convert them into a "token" (version dependent):

- `&` returns `/`
- `&&` returns `1`
- `|` returns `2`
- `||` returns `0`
- `/?` returns `<`
- `@` returns `+`
- `@()` returns `;`

---

- `@if a==a :` returns `,`
- `@for %a in () do :` returns `+`
- `@rem :` returns `-`

However, even though they have unique parsers, it still doesn't explain why they all crash. So I did some testing:

> - Remove `call`
>
> > ```
> >     C:\>set "h=/?" & for %h%
> >     %%h%% was unexpected at this time.
> > ```
>
> - Change the command to something else. (I tried all other internal commands, none works)
> - Seperate two commands:
>
> > ```
> >     C:\>set "h=/?"
> >     C:\>call for %%h%%
> >     --FOR help message--
> > ```
>
> - Add `@`
>
> > ```
> >     C:\>set "h=/?" & call for @%%h%%
> >     CRASH!!!
> > ```
>
> - Surround the scriptblock by `()`
>
> > ```
> >     C:\>set "h=/?" & call for (%%h%%)
> >     CRASH!!!
> > ```

**Summary of question**:

- What role does `call` play?
- What caused the parser to crash?

Comment: Why not ask the author of that script @npocmaka? (although I guess, there is a reason why it's listed under "bugs")

Comment: The downvote wasn't me. Why should I? I just mentioned the author to maximize your chance to get an answer. And three weeks ago? I can't remember (probably not). If you tell me which Q/A, I'll tell you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `CALL` is necessary to start a second round of the parser.

But there is a small bug (or more), in that phase it's not possible to execute any of the special commands or using `&`, `|`, `&&`, `||`, redirection or command blocks.

The cause seems to be, that the parser build internally a token graph, replacing the special things into some kind of token values.
But with `CALL` the executer doesn't know anymore how to handle them.

This code tries to execute a batch file, named `3.bat` !!!
(The name can be different, depending on the windows version)

```
set "cmd=(a) & (b)"
call %%cmd%%
```

But in your sample, the help function is triggered on a non executable token.
That seems to be the final death trigger for the executer to be completely out of sanity.

Answer (score 1):

## Summary of Research:

Calling linefeeds `\n` or `FOR`, `IF` & `REM`'s help function crashes cmd, exiting with `ERRORLEVEL` -1073741819 aka 0xC0000005, which indicates an access violation error.

First, the cmd parser tries to start `werfault` to terminate the process.
[image]

If you prematurely terminate `werfault`, an error message will appear!
[image]

> Access violation error:
>   The instruction at 0x00007FF7F18E937B referenced memory at 0x0000000000000070. The memory could not be read.

It is conjectured that `if`, `for` and `rem` uses special parsers, but when the help function is triggered by `call`, a non-command token is returned, which crashes the cmd parser.

---

Sources:

> 1. [Why I can't CALL "IF" and "FOR" neither in batch nor in the cmd?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19445153/why-i-cant-call-if-and-for-neither-in-batch-nor-in-the-cmd?noredirect=1&lq=1)
> 2. [CALL me, or better avoid call](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=1947)
> 3. [Limit CMD processing to internal commands, safer and faster?](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=2521)